# Packet cast to struct with multiple dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, struct, casting

I'm currently working on a Client/Server application, sending packets via TCP.
To read the incoming packet, I do something like this:

```
struct SomeRandomStruct
{
    int nVal1;
    int nVal2;
};

SomeRandomStruct* pStruct = reinterpret_cast<SomeRandomStruct*>(pBuffer);
```

Right now there's a small problem. Let's say I have a struct like this

```
struct SomeNewStruct
{
    int nNameLen;
    int nPassLen;
    char szName[];
    char szPass[];
};
```

Since the size/length of szName & szPass is sent in the same packet, is there a way I can set its size ,,within the reinterpret_cast" or do I have to read the packet manually?

Comment: Depends. There are two types of arrays declared in the above manner, inline and jagged. Inline arrays are declared as `char szName[128];` and whose memory is contiguous with the rest of the struct, but have a fixed size. Because the resultant data is flat, you can just do a reinterpret cast. Jagged arrays are what you have above, in which case you will have to decode the packet manually, or use an existing messaging library.

Comment: How does SomeNewStruct compile?

Comment: You can't have a struct like that, as there is no way for the compiler to figure out the location of `szPass`.

Answer (score 1):

Friendly warning:

**stop!**

Consider something like google protocol buffers to encode messages for you in a cross-platform and safe way.

Here are some reasons why:

1. How big is an int? On your machine? today? tomorrow? It's undefined in the c++ standard.
2. What is the binary representation of an int? Is it the same on the machine sending and the machine receiving? Will it always be? (If you think 'yes' then you're wrong). Again the c++ standard has nothing to say on the matter.
3. What is the padding between data members in the struct? Is it the same for all compilers on all hosts? (answer: no)
4. ask yourself why functions like `htons()` exist. They are there because not all machines are the same, but the communication between them must be.

I could go on...

Answer (score 0):

As your question is tagged C++, I'd propose you to do dynamic allocation in constructor and deallocation in destructor. That way, you could have simply pointers in your struct :

```
struct struct SomeNewStruct {
    int nNameLen;
    int nPassLen;
    char *szName;
    char *szPass;

    SomeNewStruct(int nameLen , int passLen) {
        // set and alloc... 
    }
    SomeNewStruct(SomeNewStruct &src) {
        // alloc and copy
    }
    ~SomeNewStruct() {
        // dealloc ... 
    }
}
```

You could even use `std::string` for szName and SzPass letting the STL deal with those low level allocation details :

```
struct struct SomeNewStruct {
    int nNameLen;
    int nPassLen;
    std::string szName;
    std::string szPass;
}
```